# GridView in Entity Framework 6 in WPF with c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gridview

I am working in WPF in VS2013 with linkage of database created in SQL Server 2014. I am writing simple functions like add, create, delete and update records. All function runs fine, but I want that all my records should be shown in a GridView in WPF..

I searched a lot but could not find any answer.. I wrote this code for adding records:

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();
MyNew_DBEntities db = new MyNew_DBEntities();

Student st = new Student();
st.First_Name = First_Name.Text;
st.Last_Name = Last_Name.Text;
st.Department = Department.Text;

db.Students.Add(st);
db.SaveChanges();
MessageBox.Show("Record Added Seccessfuly", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

and I want that after this addition all my record entered should be shown in GridView and so on. Similarity for deletion and update of records too.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use your DbContext and get your object graph you want to display on your grid.

```
MyNew_DBEntities db = new MyNew_DBEntities();
var StudentCollection = db.Students.ToList();
```

you *can* perform a ToList() as shown above and send to the ItemSource of the data grid.

Then set your databinding on the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding StudentCollection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FirstName">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding First_Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

However, I would set the ItemSource databinding to an ObservableCollection instead.  The ObservableCollection will automatically update the UI if the collection changes where the List won't.  The only problem is that you can't easily convert to a ObservableCollection.  You will need to write an extension method that does this work.  I usually use the following

```
public static class CollectionUtility
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> enumeration)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<T>(enumeration);
    }
}
```

if you implement this extension method now you can use this instead of the .ToList()

```
var StudentCollection = db.Students.ToObservableCollection();
```

Comment: bro i apply above method but unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: does the .ToList(); give you the collection you want?

Comment: i just want to show my data in WPF through entity framwork v6 through grid or list view whatever

Comment: If your are not getting a List of Students back from your query then it is not a WPF problem but an entity framework problem.  How are you loading your entities?   Are you using lazy or eager loading?  If you set a breakpoint on your query are you returning the expected data?

Comment: i am loading my entites through class...i already told you that i am working in entity framework...

Comment: you load an entity with eager, lazy, or explicit loading.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx